# How to rebuild a two drive raid 1 array on Linux?

Tags: raid, raid1, fakeraid

I need to rebuild a two drive (160x2) raid 1 (mirror) array. It was an Intel raid from a 7 year old Dell computer (Windows). Both drives are assumed to be functioning. The raid was created with an on-board motherboard raid program. It's been quite a while since I had to rebuild a raid, and the last time it was a raid 5 that had been created on Slackware. Where do I get started? I'm putting them in my personal machine and I'm guessing that Linux is going to be the tool to get this done.

Comment: Do you want to access the old data, or do you need a simple wipe disk and start from scratch?

Comment: It is unclear what you are actually asking here.  Normally "rebuild" in this context would mean you had a drive fail, and you want to replace it, but you said both drives are still working.

Answer (score 0):

since RAID-1 is a 1-to-1 mirror (and stripe if it was RAID 0+1) and since both drives were deemed functional, the best first attempt in my opinion would be to take one of the drives, attach it to your Linux machine and mount it read-only. It might be as simple as that. Since I have never worked with a Dell machine in my life, let alone one with an internal raid controller, this might not work but it definitely is worth a try as it is the simplest approach.

Comment: I'll give it a shot and let you know.

Comment: @Jeff did you try out what was suggested?